# IOS Safari trims large localStorage data, IONIC2 app

Tags: javascript, ionic2, mobile-safari

I am currently working on an Ionic2 app. I need to store some questions for users in localstorage. the questions json is ~70kb (when saved as .txt on desktop). It is working fine on desktop. But when viewing on IOS, the localstorage is trimmed, and not showing full value.

[image: Trimmed value of localstorage in ios]

You can see the three dots in bottom part of image.

Can someone please guide me whats going wrong here. I am using `localStorage.setItem("question_data",JSON.stringify(data));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use ionic's `Storage`, it will use sqlite instead of localStorage on Android and iOS.

> Storage is an easy way to store key/value pairs and JSON objects. Storage uses a variety of storage engines underneath, picking the best one available depending on the platform.
>   When running in a native app context, Storage will prioritize using SQLite, as it's one of the most stable and widely used file-based databases, and avoids some of the pitfalls of things like localstorage and IndexedDB, such as the OS deciding to clear out such data in low disk-space situations.

Here is the documentation: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/